# Upstart attempts to start job before mounting everything

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

```
~$ cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults    0 0
/dev/xvda2  /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig     0   2
/dev/xvda3  none    swap    sw,comment=cloudconfig  0   0
/dev/xvdf   /home/ubuntu/apps   auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig     0       0
```

I have apps stored into an EBS disk (EC2), this is what happens:

```
[8478660.968721] init: Failed to spawn rails main process: unable to change working directory: No such file or directory
[8478661.020311] init: failsafe main process (540) killed by TERM signal
[8478661.129133] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
[8478661.137579] EXT3-fs (xvda2): using internal journal
[8478661.137587] EXT3-fs (xvda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
[8478661.375571] Adding 917500k swap on /dev/xvda3.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:917500k SS
[8478661.588418] EXT4-fs (xvdf): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

It appears that the app is trying to start well before the last filesystem has been mounted, upstart script bits:

`start on filesystem and started networking`

...

`chdir /home/ubuntu/apps/rails/current`

The chdir fails immediately because the filesystem has not been mounted yet.

Instead of `networking` I also tried other events (specifying INET, etc.) to no avail.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing /etc/fstab solved the issue.

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults    0 0
/dev/xvda2  /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig     0   2
/dev/xvda3  none    swap    sw,comment=cloudconfig  0   0
/dev/xvdf   /home/ubuntu/apps   auto    defaults,comment=apps     0       1
```